# Why does sp_executesql run slower when parameters are passed as arguments

Tags: .net, sql, sql-server, linq

Query 1: (lightning fast)

```
sp_executesql "select * from tablesView where Id = 1"
```

vs.

Query 2: (too slow)

```
sp_executesql "select * from tablesView where Id = @Id", N"@Id int", @Id=1
```

`tablesView - a view containing multiple joins`

LINQ always converts queries to Query2 form and hence the performance is really bad.

Questions: I need reason for query2 slowness, and any resolution if there's one. 
And a resolution for LINQ.

----Additional comments:

The performance hit is definitely because of the 2 columns which are using ranking functions(row_number) but I can't avoid them I need them.

Comment: Do you have a lot of rows with ID = 1?

Comment: @Lasse, even if I have 50 records, the difference is huge. like 0 sec vs 10 sec, one thing is select * from table, is generally a view with lot of joins.

Comment: What is the datatype passed in for `@id`? You may have an implicit cast going on preventing use of an index.

Comment: I can't tell if that answered my question or if you said "even if I have 50 rows in total in my table...". Do you have a lot of rows with ID = 1. It's a yes or no question, or possibly "what do you mean by 'a lot'". Either way... do you have a lot of rows with ID = 1?

Comment: You should be able to look at the query plans and see if there is any difference. In the former case, it may be able to perform an optimization. But obviously there would be some overhead for parameter replacement.

Comment: @Lasse tables could be huge, but records against id=1 could be 50, 100 of that range. Even then its slow.

Comment: @WhoIsNinja - But what is the datatype declared in the `sp_executesql` call?

Comment: @WhoIsNinja - Ah right. You probably have a parameter sniffing issue then. The parameterised plan will have been compiled according to the value first passed in for `@id`, that may have been considerably more (or less) selective than 1 is. The plan compiled for that value may not be suitable for others.

Comment: @Martin, whats param sniffing issue?

Comment: @Martin, I'm trying to read on internet about this, but any resolution?

Comment: @WhoIsNinja - The ususal resolutions are to use query hints such as `OPTIMIZE FOR` or `RECOMPILE`. Not sure how to do this from LINQ though.

Answer (score 7):

I'm going to go out on a limb here and assume that you have a lot of rows where ID = 1.

If not, please correct me.

One possible reason that SQL Server is processing your query slow is that it looks at the query and goes:

> hmm, I wonder what he's going to pass for that parameter.
>   is it going to be 1? where I have about a gazillion rows?
>   or perhaps 1742, where I have just 3
>   I just don't know, I better do a table scan to be sure to produce an execution plan that will cover all my bases

If a column, or a column set, has low selectivity (ie. the number of unique values is far less than the number of rows), SQL Server will sometimes revert to a tablescan or similar, just to get all rows deterministically.

At least that's been my experience. In particular I've seen the same behavior when doing date range selects on tables with time-bound data, doing a `WHERE dt <= @dt AND dt >= @dt` to get all rows where @dt is inside a period of time in that row, reverts to a table-scan, and then when I place the actual date into the SQL as a literal it runs far faster.

The problem here is the selectivity, SQL Server doesn't know how to best cater for all scenarios when building an execution plan for your statement, so it'll try to guess.

Try adding a query hint to specify a *typical* value for the parameter, ie.:

```
sp_executesql "select * from tablesView where Id = @Id option (optimize for (@id = 1742))", N"@Id int", @Id=1
```

Comment: optimize for doesn't help, moroever i can't ask linq to add optimize inside the query it builds. :(

Comment: And speaking of records, there will be million records returned if there is no where clause in this query, as the view contains joins between huge tables

Comment: 1. Who said anything about "No where clause"? and 2. Did you try executing the SQL with an optimize for clause and looking at the differences? and 3) ... is an ORM that doesn't know your data still the best approach?

Comment: yet another reason why using an ORM is not always a good choice.

Answer (score 2):

This could be a **parameter sniffing** problem. Try including the line:

```
OPTION (RECOMPILE)
```

at the end of your SQL query.

There is an article here explaining what parameter sniffing is: http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx

Comment: Although I couldn't use this directly, it was the answer to my problem, namely that parameters were causing table scans instead of using indexes. Using OPTION (RECOMPILE) did force the underlying view to use a plan making uses of table indexes. Unfortunately I couldn't make use of this as my SQL middleware parser cannot accept the syntax. My workaround was to build the SQL without the parameters, effectively hard coding the values into the query. No ideal, but it avoided the query being turned into sp_executesql.

Answer (score 0):

1. Avoid using SELECT *
2. ADO.NET 3.5 there is "parameter quessing" in Linq 1=TINYINT 2345=SMALLINT 76357242=INT ..
   in ADO.NET 4.0 parameter quessing is replaced with default INT data type  1=INT, 2335=INT ,76357242=INT)

Comment: I never use select * , this was just for example.