# Nhibernate generate plain sql query instead of execution statement

Tags: nhibernate

Using SQL profiler, I was able to find the query generated from Nhibernate was executed in the

```
EXEC sp_executesql N'select ...'
```

fashion.
I am wondering if there is any way to force Nhibernate to generate the plain

```
Select ...
```

statement instead.

The reason I want this is because apparently SQL Server generated different execution plans for them, and in my scenario, the plain "select ..." runs MUCH faster.

-----Update----- Nov 30, 2012

I just found this link [Why does sp_executesql run slower when parameters are passed as arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438135/why-does-sp-executesql-run-slower-when-parameters-are-passed-as-arguments)

And I believe the popular answer(with 4 up votes upto now) explained the reason well.

So Now the question is

**Can I generate a straight query instead of parametrized one using nhibernate?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, NHibernate issues commands to SQL Server using sp_executesql and this cannot be changed. However, you should be able to troubleshoot any slow queries to resolve the performance issues. The first thing that I would like at is to check that the parameters supplied with the sp_executesql call have the same data types as the columns they reference.

Comment: Thanks! I just updated the question. Is there anyway to generate straight query instead of parametrized ones?

Answer (score 0):

In your Session Factory configuration you can enable `ShowSql`. This will output the SQL queries generated to the output window while you are debugging. You'll need to make sure to set your `BatchSize` to 0 to see all the queries. If batching is enabled, you won't be able to see the queries it groups up (to optimize performance).

NHibernate Profiler is also an Invaluable (but commercial) tool for debugging your code. http://www.hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf

Comment: I am using NHProfiler, that is how I get my plain sql statement. The conclusion of the plain statements is faster was drawn by running this plain statement from SSMS and running my application, and then watch the duration in SQL Profiler.

Answer (score 0):

You should clear your execution plans on your server and than try agian:

```
DBCC FREEPROCCACHE
```

And/or you can force a recompilation of the execution plan by injecting option(recompile) into your query.

Answer (score 0):

Nhibernate uses log4net and you just need to add an appender as mentioned here incase you are using log4net:

https://devio.wordpress.com/2010/04/14/logging-sql-statements-generated-by-nhibernate/

For example:

```
<appender name="DebugSQL" type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender">
  <param name="File" value=".\nhdb.log"/>
  <param name="AppendToFile" value="true" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern
      value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger [%property{NDC}] - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>

<logger name="NHibernate.SQL" additivity="false">
  <level value="DEBUG" />
  <appender-ref ref="DebugSQL" />
</logger>
```