# Nhibernate add Option for queries

Tags: nhibernate

I have recently had performance problem with Nhibernate generated SQL as described in

[Nhibernate generate plain sql query instead of execution statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13636197/nhibernate-generate-plain-sql-query-instead-of-execution-statement)

I also found a link describing similar experience from the one and only Jeff Atwood at

http://legeronline.blogspot.ca/2009/03/evils-of-slow-paramaterized-query-plans.html

Does anyone know if there is anyway to add an "Optimize Uknown" option to Nhibernate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- you could look into extending the MsSqlDialect or
- implement IConnectionProvider to inject your own commandwrapper which adds the hint when `ExecuteReader()` is called

Answer (score 3):

This example is a little more verbose:

```
public class OptionInterceptor: EmptyInterceptor
{
    public override SqlString OnPrepareStatement(SqlString sql)
    {
        var parameters = sql.GetParameters();
        var paramCount = parameters.Count();

        if (paramCount == 0)
            return sql;

        string optionString = " OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR (";

        for (var i = 0; i < paramCount; i++)
        {
            var comma = i > 0 ? "," : string.Empty;
            optionString = optionString + comma + "@p" + i + " UNKNOWN";
        }

        optionString = optionString + "))";

        var builder = new SqlStringBuilder(sql);

        builder.Add(optionString);

        return builder.ToSqlString();
    }
}
```

Then in your sessionfactory/initializer:

```
configuration.ExposeConfiguration(x =>
    {
        x.SetInterceptor(new OptionInterceptor());
    });
```

Comment: I believe you can also simply append `" OPTION (OPTIMIZE FOR UNKNOWN)"`, in which case all parameters are considered unknown (no need to specify all of them). Also, shouldn't it be `if (sql.GetParameterCount() == 0) return sql;`?

Comment: @Groo yep, and yep